# Draw image at specific position onto an existing image

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone 7 application, I have a large image and i want to draw another small image (from an image folder) in specific position (x, y) on top of the large image.  How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to change the large image or do you want to 'stack' the images in the UI?

Comment: no i will not change the large image i want to stack the images in the UI

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images in a canvas and position them

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="BigImage.jpg"/>
    <Image Source="SmallImage.jpg" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50" />
</Canvas>
```

Depending on your requirements/setup you could also nest them in a Grid and use the Margin properties of the images.